# Backbonejs collection fetch error detect XHR object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

In my backbone collection, I have

```
fetch_data: function(data, callback) {
  this.fetch({
    data: data,
    success: callback,
    error: function() {
      // detect of HTTP code here
    }
  });
}
```

And I want to check the HTTP header status code within error. How can I access XHR object within the error function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
fetch_data: function(data, callback) {
  this.fetch({
    data: data,
    success: callback,
    error: function(model,resp) {
      console.log(resp.status);   // 404..etc.
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch

It looks as though error is passed an xhr object as its second argument.

So, change your code to be as follows:

```
fetch_data: function(data, callback) {
  this.fetch({
    data: data,
    success: callback,
    error: function(model, xhr, options) {
      // do something with the xhr argument here. 
    }
  });
```

}